Input text losing focus upon onChange
I have a simple table of ingredients where by default three rows are generated and maintained by React useState [ingredients,setIngredients]. Typing / changing the text with trigger onChange function that in turn run setIngredients.
When I type in the textbox, it loses focus and caret disappears. I have added a unique key to each input and yet it still loses focus. If I inspect and look at the elements, it seems that the entire <tbody> rerenders.
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';


const IngredientsTable = () => {
  const [rowsGenerated, setRowsGenerated] = useState(3);

  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState({
    1: { id: '1', name: '', proportion: '' },
    2: { id: '2', name: '', proportion: '' },
    3: { id: '3', name: '', proportion: '' },
  });

 
  const onFieldChange = ({ value, id, field }) => {
    console.log('onFieldChange triggered', { id, value, field });
    setIngredients((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [id]: { ...prevState[id], [field]: value },
    }));
  };

  const Row = ({ rowId, name, proportion }) => (
    <Fragment>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input
            id={rowId + 'name'}
            key={rowId + 'name'}
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) =>
              onFieldChange({
                id: rowId,
                field: 'name',
                value: e.target.value,
              })
            }
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            id={rowId + 'proportion'}
            key={rowId + 'proportion'}
            type="text"
            value={proportion}
            onChange={(e) =>
              onFieldChange({
                id: rowId,
                field: 'proportion',
                value: e.target.value,
              })
            }
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button">-</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </Fragment>
  );

  const addRow = () => {
    setRowsGenerated((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    setIngredients((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [rowsGenerated + 1]: { id: rowsGenerated + 1, name: '', proportion: '' },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="ingredient_table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={{ width: '62%' }}>Name </th>
            <th style={{ width: '30%' }}>Proportion %</th>
            <th style={{ width: '8%' }}></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(ingredients).map((id, i) => {
            const rowId = id;
            return (
              <Row
                key={`ingredient${rowId}`}
                rowId={rowId}
                name={ingredients[rowId].name}
                proportion={ingredients[rowId].proportion}
              />
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button className="ingredient_add_row_button" onClick={addRow}>
        Add row
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default IngredientsTable;


You're creating your Row component inside of IngredientsTable component, don't do that, instead, create it outside, and pass the values it needs as props

Read https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#nesting-and-organizing-components and more specifically the "Pitfall" section

You are creating a <Row> component inside the <IngredientsTable> component, this causes issues, move the <Row> outside the other component and your issue is fixed


const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Row = ({ rowId, name, proportion, onFieldChange }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input
            id={rowId + 'name'}
            key={rowId + 'name'}
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) =>
              onFieldChange({
                id: rowId,
                field: 'name',
                value: e.target.value,
              })
            }
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            id={rowId + 'proportion'}
            key={rowId + 'proportion'}
            type="text"
            value={proportion}
            onChange={(e) =>
              onFieldChange({
                id: rowId,
                field: 'proportion',
                value: e.target.value,
              })
            }
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button">-</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
  
const IngredientsTable = () => {
  const [rowsGenerated, setRowsGenerated] = useState(3);

  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState({
    1: { id: '1', name: '', proportion: '' },
    2: { id: '2', name: '', proportion: '' },
    3: { id: '3', name: '', proportion: '' },
  });

 
  const onFieldChange = ({ value, id, field }) => {
    //console.log('onFieldChange triggered', { id, value, field });
    setIngredients((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [id]: { ...prevState[id], [field]: value },
    }));
  };


  const addRow = () => {
    setRowsGenerated((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    setIngredients((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [rowsGenerated + 1]: { id: rowsGenerated + 1, name: '', proportion: '' },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="ingredient_table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={{ width: '62%' }}>Name </th>
            <th style={{ width: '30%' }}>Proportion %</th>
            <th style={{ width: '8%' }}></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(ingredients).map((id, i) => {
            const rowId = id;
            return (
              <Row
                key={`ingredient${rowId}`}
                rowId={rowId}
                name={ingredients[rowId].name}
                proportion={ingredients[rowId].proportion}
                onFieldChange={onFieldChange}
              />
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button className="ingredient_add_row_button" onClick={addRow}>
        Add row
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<IngredientsTable />, document.getElementById("react"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>



